# Bulk Update wordpress core & its plugins locally

Tags: wordpress, workflow, updates, bulk

I am many wordpress sites developed locally. Once the site is finished, I upload to remote.

Now the problem is that there are too many sites and its plugins that needs to be updated. It has been time consuming and error prone to update those sites and plugins one by one.

Can anybody suggest their workflow in such scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [InfiniteWP](http://infinitewp.com/) to manage updates remotely.

You set "the server" up on your own webhost and install plugins in the sites you want to manage. From then on you can log in on your webhost, add sites which have the plugin installed and can then choose which updates to make etc.

Another solution like this would be [MainWP](https://mainwp.com/), which I have no experience with.

Comment: Thanks. 
I have only tried InfiniteWP in live running servers, never tired in localhost. If I install it in a localhost and manage the sites, don't you think there will be issues when moving to the live server.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant you want to have tool to update the sites when working online. Nevertheless, Infinite WP (IWP) should work for you. Simply remove the sites from your IWP Dashboard and readd them, so you get the new (live) URLs in IWP. You might also de- and reactivate the IWP plugin in the sites if you want a clean start again.